# Filtering data in arrays and keeping the same shape in axis 1

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to get some specific values given a dataframe using pandas and numpy.

My process right now is as it follows:

> In[1]: df = pd.read_csv(file)
>
> In[2]: a = df[df.columns[1]].values

Right now a has the following shape:

> In[3]: a.shape
>
> Out[4]: (8640, 1)

When I filter it out to get the values that match a given condition I don't get the same shape in the axis 1:

> In[5]: b = a[a>100]
>
> In[6]: b.shape
>
> Out[7]: (3834,)

Right now I'm reshaping the new arrays everytime I filter them, however this is making my code look really messy and uncomfortable:

> In[8]: (b.reshape(b.size,1)).shape
>
> Out[9]: (3834, 1)

I really need it to have the shape (x, 1) in order to use some other functions, so is it any way of getting that shape everytime I filter out the values without having to reshape it constantly?

EDIT:

The main reason I need to do this reshaping is that I need to get the minimum value in every row for two arrays with the same number of rows. What I use is np.min and np.concatenate.
For example:
av is the mean of 5 different columns in my dataframe:

> av = np.mean(myColumns,axis=1)

Which has shape (8640, )
med is the median for the same columns:

> med = np.median(myColumns,axis=1)

And when I try to get the minimum values I have the next error:

> np.min(np.concatenate((av,med),axis=1),axis=1) Traceback (most recent
>   call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       np.min(np.concatenate((av,med),axis=1),axis=1)
>
> AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1

However, if I reshape av and med it works fine:

> np.min(np.concatenate((av.reshape(av.size,1),med.reshape(av.size,1)),axis=1),axis=1)
>   Out[232]: array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.])

Comment: On my end, I tried running `df[df.columns[0]].values.shape` on some dataframe and got `(x,)` and not `(x,1)`. Are you sure you're copying the code as you ran it? Alternatively, what version of `pandas` and `numpy` are you using?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I wrote it differently. In my code I'm loading the arrays in a different way:  `a=df.filter(regex="Power").values`, and my dataframe has just one column with the string "Power" in its name.

Comment: Okay, now I did the same and got `(x,1)`. However, I'm getting another result in the second line: if I do `a = df[[df.columns[0]]]` for example (which has shape `(x,1)`), I run `b=a[a>0]` and still get shape `(x,1)`.

Comment: If I have an array a with shape `(x,1)` and I run `b=a[a>0]` it has shape (if a is always positive) `(x,)` and not `(x,1)`. My pandas version is `'0.23.4'` and my numpy version is `'1.16.4'`. I edited the original question to clarify what I'm having troubles with.

Comment: OK, I get what was the difference. See if my answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `np.take(a, np.where(a>100)[0], axis=0)` for keeping the same shape as original

Answer (score 0):

If you really need this shape, this code gives shape `(..., 1)` and it's not *that* ugly:

```
np.expand_dims(a, 1)
```

or

```
a[:, np.newaxis]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code is not too heavy that you have to use `numpy` for performance, you can stick with `pandas` objects (DataFrame/Series) and maintain shape.

For example, take this example df (which, I must add, you should've provided with your question):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(7,3), columns=['a','b','c'])
df
    a           b           c
0   0.382530    0.748674    0.186446
1   0.142991    0.965972    0.299884
2   0.568910    0.469341    0.896786
3   0.452816    0.021598    0.989637
4   0.884955    0.738519    0.082460
5   0.944797    0.103953    0.287005
6   0.379389    0.593280    0.832720
```

To create an object with shape `(7,1)` you can use `x = df[['a']]`, which is a dataframe with one column (compare with `x=df['a']`, which is a Series with shape `(7,)`).

Now, if I move on to a numpy array by using `y=x.values`, I still get the same shape (both x and y have shapes (7,1)).

However, both react differently to boolean indexing: calling `y[y>0.3]` will return an array with shape (6,), while calling `x[x>0.3]` will return ... a dataframe with shape (7,1). Let's see:

array:

```
y[y>0.3]
array([0.38252971, 0.56890993, 0.45281553, 0.88495521, 0.94479716,
       0.37938899])
```

dataframe:

```
x[x>0.3]
    a
0   0.382530
1   NaN
2   0.568910
3   0.452816
4   0.884955
5   0.944797
6   0.379389
```

So, to get a series with the shape that you want (6,1), you can use

```
x[x['a']>0.3]
```

which returns

```
    a
0   0.382530
2   0.568910
3   0.452816
4   0.884955
5   0.944797
6   0.379389
```

And then, only after doing all of your manipulations, you can call the `.values` at the end at obtain a numpy array with the desired result.

Now, generally speaking, manipulation on arrays are faster than on pandas objects, but working with pandas objects is easier, especially if you have lots of data processing to do. 
You might prefer to work with numpy all the way, but the pandas option is worth knowing, and in my opinion is easier and simpler.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it was really clarifying.

Unfortunately my dataframe has around 4000 columns and using pandas (which I prefer because it's easier for me) is way too slow for my calculations. In my code I use pandas to load the desired columns and then do the calculations with numpy.

Comment: Ah, well. It was worth a shot.